# Is it possible to output 6 channel PCM from a device running iOS8+?

Tags: ios, audio, usb, pcm

I've been asked to investigate a 5.1 surround system that uses an iOS device as the primary source (iOS 8+ is fine).  Some audio files that we'd want to playback are 24/96 multichannel FLAC (similar to DVD-A).

I've seen various 2 channel DACs for iOS. I've also found iOS SPDIF output available, but that's also only 2 channels for uncompressed PCM.

I've also read up that iOS8 has reasonably broad USB Class Audio 2.0 support.  That seems the most likely candidate for supporting 6 channel PCM over USB (using the lightning to USB adapter).  However, I still can't find any examples of folks actually getting uncompressed, 6 channel audio out of any combination of iOS hardware and APIs.

Am I chasing a goose here, or is this feasible?

Comment: Try looking into `AudioStreamBasicDescription` . You could set the mChannelsPerFrame property to the number of channels that you'd need. Then set the other properties appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to play multichannel audio using the following setup:

iPad -> lightning to USB adaptor -> Powered USB hub -> USB sound card

I used an application Auria for iPad.

I am trying to figure out how to enumerate multichannel audio devices on iOS so my App can add support to 5.1 and 7.1 surround sound playback